# What is a static buffer priority (SBP) service discipline?

Tags: queueing, service-discipline, priority-queue

In [Anton Braverman *et al* 2023](https://arxiv.org/abs/2302.05791) they mention their assumed service discipline:

> "Our results assume that the network operates under a static buffer priority (SBP) service discipline and require three additional conditions: stability, state space collapse, and a certain matrix being “tight” (see Definition 3.2).

I don't know what SBP is, their Definition 3.2 is for a *tight system* that doesn't seem to make mention of SBP.

Being a service discipline, an SBP must be some sort of rule that decide which customer gets served next. The word "static" suggests that something is not changing.

"Buffer" makes me think of the accumulating patients, but it is very unclear what the meaning is here.

"Priority" is clear enough in that there should be an order relation on the customers for which ones get serviced. It could be a total order, fully-determining the next customer. Or it could be a partial order in which further rules or a distribution decide which customer gets served next within a topological generation of the Hasse graph.

But that's just my impressions based on how I understand those individual words.

What is SBP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did not read far enough before asking. Here the same paper defines SBP:

> In this paper, we restrict our discipline to static buffer priority (SBP), which is defined below. **Under an SBP discipline, the
> classes at each station are assigned a fixed ranking.** When the server switches from one
> job to another, the new job will be taken from the leading (or longest waiting) job at the
> highest ranking non-empty class at the server’s station. We assume that the ranking is
> strict, i.e., there is no tie in the ranking. We also assume that the service discipline is
> preemptive-resume. That is, when a job, with a higher rank than the one currently being
> served, arrives at the server’s station, the service of the current job is interrupted. When
> service of all jobs with higher ranks is completed, the interrupted service continues from
> where it left off.